# Library used by kernel module and user application

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, yocto

I'm working with yocto and trying to use a library within a kernel module and an user application.

- The **kernel module** handles an UART interface
- the **library** (written in C) defines a high-level protocol. Therefore, it provides several functions (e.g. interrupt callback) and a static struct that contains all kind of information (configuration, received and transmitted messages, ...)
- The **user application** should be called in the command line like: `app param1 param2 ...`

What is the best way to do that? I have my kernel module and my user application running, but everytime I try to implement the shared library, it gets really messy and I get errors (mostly because of the include files).

Is there a good example for such a problem or some keywords that could help?

Because the library stores some information locally, it is not suitable to copy the files in both directories.

Thanks in advance!

---

So, this is the situation in more detail:

#### UART

UART folder structure:

- / recipes-myrecipes

  - / uart

    - uart_1.0.bb
    - / uart-1.0

      - Makefile
      - / src / altera_uart.c
      - / inc / altera_uart.h

***uart_1.0.bb***

```
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/GPL-                
2.0;md5=801f80980d171dd6425610833a22dbe6"

inherit module


SRC_URI = " \
       file://inc/altera_uart.h \
       file://src/altera_uart.c \
           file://Makefile \
          "
S = "${WORKDIR}"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "cyclone5"
```

***Makefile***

```
obj-m:= uart.o

uart-objs := ./src/altera_uart.o

SRC := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC)

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
    rm -f Module.markers Module.symvers modules.order
    rm -rf .tmp_versions Modules.symvers
```

`bitbake uart` works without errors.

#### User application

My app is called tbdriver. So here is the folder structure:

- / recipes-myrecipes

  - tbdriver_1.0.bb
  - / tbdriver-1.0

    - tbdriver.c
    - tbdriver.h

***tbdriver_1.0.bb***

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = " \
       file://tbdriver.c \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}" 

do_compile() {
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${WORKDIR}/tbdriver.c -o tbdriver
}

do_install() {
  install -d ${D}${bindir} 
  install -m 0755 tbdriver ${D}${bindir} 
}
```

`bitbake tbdriver` works without errors.

#### What I tried

So, I added the library (debug_protocol) to the kernel module folder, added them in the Makefile and the .bb. So, `bitbake uart` still works without errors.

- / recipes-myrecipes

  - / uart

    - uart_1.0.bb
    - / uart-1.0

      - Makefile
      - / src

        - altera_uart.c
        - debug_protocol.c
      - / inc

        - altera_uart.h
        - debug_protocol.h

Then I tried to add the debug_protocol.h to the tbdriver in order to get access to its functions as well. (By the way, I tried a lot of different versions)

***tbdriver_1.0.bb***

```
...
SRC_URI = " \
       file://../../uart/uart-1.0/src/debug_protocol.h \
       file://../../uart/uart-1.0/src/debug_protocol.c \
       file://tbdriver.c \
          "
...
```

#### Error

```
WARNING: tbdriver-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL file://../../uart/uart-1.0/src/debug_protocol.h, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: tbdriver-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://../../uart/uart-1.0/src/debug_protocol.h anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
   ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver-1.0/poky
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver/poky
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/files/poky
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver-1.0/cyclone5
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver/cyclone5
   ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/files/cyclone5
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver-1.0/armv7a
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver/armv7a
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/files/armv7a
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver-1.0/arm
     ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver/arm
     ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/files/arm
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver-1.0/
     ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver/
    ../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/files/
    .../yocto/build/downloads
ERROR: tbdriver-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'file://../../uart/uart-1.0/src/debug_protocol.h'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: tbdriver-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ../yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/tbdriver/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.7039
ERROR: Task (/../meta-ines/recipes-myrecipes/tbdriver/tbdriver_1.0.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

#### Question

Is it even possible to do what I am trying?

Yes? -> Do you have a link to an example or a hint?

No? What would be the alternative? Syscall? Seems not suitable for me, since I want to register functions with function pointers from both sides (UART & App). But please tell me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*everytime I try to implement the shared library, it gets really messy and I get errors*" dare to show some of the tries you did, along with the errors they are provoking?

Comment: The kernel does not use shared libraries and does not share memory with userspace programs.  It therefore also does not call user functions directly (e.g. callbacks) nor can userspace programs call kernel functions directly -- that's what the system call interface is all about (though the C library may make this less than totally apparent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood how to use library. From description I understand that you have some piece of code/algo/data that you want to use in both User space app and Kernel module. AFAIK you can't just create a library and share them between user-kernel space to call each other's function.

To access userspace from kernel and vice versa you can use syscall, ioctl, device driver read/write etc.
[image]

For your specific application, you may register ioctl in driver and use them to initiate message passing from user to kernel space. You may also register a character driver in driver and perform read/write operation on device file to get/send a little large data.